# Ubuntu find and replace in files of current directory recursively

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, search, find

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and Magento website in my Local System.

Now I have a module directory in which I want to replace every occurrence of "Magento\Module" with "MyCompany\Module" in all files inside this current folder and it's sub-directories recursively ofcourse, but I guess it's not working due to "\" are there in my search and replace string.

I have already tried:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g" {} \;
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Please help anyone, it's urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is likely consuming one of the escapes:

```
$ echo sed "s/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g"
sed s/Magento\Module/MyCompany\Module/g
```

So either add an additional escape or single-quote the entire expression:

```
$ echo sed "s/Magento\\\Module/MyCompany\\\Module/g"
sed s/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g

$ echo sed 's/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g'
sed s/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g
```

Testing it:

```
$ echo 'every occurrence of "Magento\Module"' | sed 's/Magento\\Module/MyCompany\\Module/g'
every occurrence of "MyCompany\Module"
```

Comment: `@steeldriver` Thanks your anwser is working perfectly, can you let me know how to replace directory names as well in this command itself along with filenames ?

Comment: @VickyDev can you edit your question to include examples?